# I keep getting this error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

Whenever I run my code i keep getting this error: 'Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.'

I understand why it's happening, but I don't know how else to write my code for it to do exactly what i want.

my code is:

```
 
const CheckoutComponent = () => {
    const { checkoutProducts } = useSelector((state)=> state?.allCartProducts);
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

    const costOfItems = ()=> {
        let itemsTotalCost = 0;
        checkoutProducts?.map((product)=> {
          itemsTotalCost += product?.price * product?.quantity;
        })
        return itemsTotalCost;
    }

   useEffect(()=> {
    setTotalPrice(costOfItems());

})

  return (
    <h1>The total amount is {totalPrice}</h1>
)

}
```

I'm executing the map throughout 'checkoutProducts' array because I want to get the product(result of multiplication) of the price and quantity properties of each object inside the array. Then, I sum up everything together before returning it. That's what the following function achieves.

```
const costOfItems = ()=> {
        let itemsTotalCost = 0;
        checkoutProducts?.map((product)=> {
          itemsTotalCost += product?.price * product?.quantity;
        })
        return itemsTotalCost;
    }
```

After that, I'm calling this function inside of a UseEffect hook with no dependencies because I want it to render whenever anything in the component changes. I'm also using the returned value of this function to set the state 'totalPrice' so that I can refer to it later on. Hence the following line of code:

```
   useEffect(()=> {
    setTotalPrice(costOfItems());

})

  return (
    <h1>The total amount is {totalPrice}</h1>
)
```

But I keep getting that error regardless of whether I add a dependency array to the UseEffect hook, I remove the array, or set the dependency to the function, 'costOfItems':

```
// doesn't work
 useEffect(()=> {
    setTotalPrice(costOfItems());

})

// doesn't work either
 useEffect(()=> {
    setTotalPrice(costOfItems());

}, [])

// doesn't work too
 useEffect(()=> {
    setTotalPrice(costOfItems());

}, [costOfItems])
```

This is the point where i'm stuck because I can't attach the calling of that function to an 'onClick' of any element in the jsx since I want that function to run either when the component is first mounted, or when anything at all changes in the component. Please, is there some other way I can achieve that?

Comment: FYI optional chaining won't do much for you with how you're using it: `checkoutProducts?.map(...)`, if not defined, will give you `map is not a function` and the optional chainings for `product` will absolutely do nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243216/error-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-this-can-happen-when-a-component-calls-set)

Comment: Please provide a bit more context. Make sure you post the [mre]; it's hard to see what you're doing.

Comment: @Joel thanks for the reference, but it actually doesn't. I read the article previously but unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: You might not need useEffect. See https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Comment: @code I just did. Please, could you take another look at the question

Comment: @IcyIcicle this was so helpful!! I literally found a solution, I'm so grateful thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You forgot to use dependency array

Now using `setTotalPrice` triggers this `useEffect` which causes infinite loop

### Solution

Add the dependency array

```
useEffect(()=> {
  setTotalPrice(costOfItems());
}, [costOfItems])
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I tried this already and it doesn't work.